# Liferay/Tomcat 7 with SSL gets no session with DNS

Tags: tomcat, ssl, dns, liferay, httpsession

I'm a little bit confused.

I have configured a Liferay/Tomcat 7 Server with SSL (https:8443) which works correctly.

Everything works fine, if I call the server by ip, so like https://192.168.4.44 or 215.44.24.67. (These are just samples...) and it opens correctly in my webbrowser.

But when I'm trying to get access to the server by opening the server with the dns in the browser, so like https://myname.mycompany.com, the browser gets no session and no cookie. If I disable cookies in my browser I get an endless loop.

For this the images in my jsf portlet are not getting loaded. If I refresh the page, everything gets loaded and finally there is a session.

I made some entries in iptables to use SSL:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --destination-port 443 -j ACCEPT 
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j REDIRECT -p tcp --destination-port 443 --to-ports 8443 
sudo /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --destination-port 80 -j ACCEPT 
sudo /sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j REDIRECT -p tcp --destination-port 80 --to-ports 1026
```

Are there any tomcat experts in here who can help me out?

Greetings from Austria,

Johann